# To find all words starting with, for example "Var" in notepad++

Tags: notepad++

How to find and replace all words starting with the word "Var" in Notepad++. I dont want to replace the whole line, only that particular word.
Is it possible??

Answer (score 4):

You may use a regex pattern with word boundaries.  Try searching for:

```
\b(Var.*?)\b
```

Then replace with whatever you want.  Do this search/replace in regex mode.

Answer (score 2):

This will replace `Var`, `Variable` or `Var12` but not `aVar`

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\bVar\w*`
- Replace with: `What you want`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\b      : word boundary, make sure we don't have a word character before
Var     : literally Var
\w*     : 0 or more word character (i.e. [a-zA-0-9_])
```